# Get specific values

Tags: r

I created a Box Plot from a dataframe and I'd like to get out the amount of customer which attrited. You can see at education lvl 5 the blue area is most important to know.

```
ggplot(raw_data, aes(x=Attrition_Flag)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(Education_Level)), width = 0.5) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) + 
  labs(title="Histogram on Categorical Variable", 
       subtitle="Attrition_Flag across Education_Level")
```

[image]

I tried If and for loops but it didn't work out.
If you need the dataset you can download it here
https://www.kaggle.com/sakshigoyal7/credit-card-customers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking just to subset your data. Since you are already using `ggplot2`, we can use `dplyr`'s `filter` function

```
library(dplyr)
raw_data %>% 
  filter(Attrition_Flag == "Attrited Customer")
```

If you specifically want `Education_level == 5` just add this to your filter

```
raw_data %>% 
  filter(Attrition_Flag == "Attrited Customer",
         Education_Level == 'Post-Graduate')
```

Note that `Education_Level` is stored as a character vector, so you will have to specify the specific level as a string. There is also no need to use `factor` when plotting these.